# How do I stop this infinite loop if the wrong number is guessed?

Tags: loops

I am a real real real beginner in programming so please bear with me and explain it to me like I am an idiot.

If I put a couple numbers in stdin my output is exactly what I want but if I enter the wrong number the output is just an infinite loop of each `wrong` expressions.

How can I stop this loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int number;

    printf("Enter the best number in the world!\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if(number > 22)
        {
            printf("WRONG, too high! Guess again\n");

        }

        if(number <22)
        {
            printf("WRONG, too low! Guess again\n");

        }
        if(number == 22)
        {
            printf("Clever girl <now imagine that scene from Jurrassic Park>\n");
            break;
        }

    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(1)
```

Will run forever.  Try

```
while (number != 22)
```

You could then also move the answer for the "correct" number outside the loop, rather than using a break.

I agree with the other answers that only one scanf is needed, and based on the intended output you have described (which I'm not sure I entirely understand), it should be inside the loop.

Comment: So I can just take out the first `scanf`? Also, I tried `while (number != 22)` and it's still looping

Comment: Do you want it to keep asking for numbers until you pick the right one? Or just ask once?

Comment: So in that case you only need one scanf, and it should be inside the loop. You may also want the instructions repeated (I.e. "Try again") or some such thing also in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `while(1)` above your first `printf` and remove the second `scanf`. With that change, your program will loop, prompting with each loop, until a correct answer is entered, then it will exit.

Another option would be to instead remove the first `scanf`.